# Upload large ContentVersion records

Tags: javascript-remoting, contentversion, remote-action

I'm using a `@RemoteAction` to upload files to Salesforce, saving them as `ContentVersion` (Chatter files). I'm uploading the `base64` Blob of the file.
This works great for small (`<1MB`) files.
I am NOT using lightning components for this. This is our Angular app calling a remote action with a file that the user uploaded.
Specifically the error I am getting is:

```
POST https://<instance>.visual.force.com/apexremote net:: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unable to connect to the server (communication failure).
```

From what I can tell, this is because of the HTTP POST size limit of 1MB.
Now, if you use the Salesforce-y method (directly uploading a file or embedding Chatter in a VF page) then you're good for 2GB.
How can I do that from my Angular app? Do I need to chunkify the blob myself? Is there a way for me to create a ContentVersion piecemeal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I solved this.
Sort of.
My solution was to forgo the use of a `@RemoteAction` and instead use Salesforce's REST services.
For those following at home home, there are two ways to do this:
1. The easy way, use [JSForce](https://jsforce.github.io/).
2. The stupid way (which I ended up using for reasons), roll your own `XmlHttpRequest` calls.
Both are essentially the same (behind the scenes JSForce uses `XmlHttpRequest` to do its thing), so the limit seems to be 25MB.
EDIT: For the adventurous, here's some boilerplate code.

```
let targetUrl = baseUrl + '/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/ContentVersion';
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', targetUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionId);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = myCallbackFunction;
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({PathOnClient : fileName, VersionData : base64data});
```

EDIT September 2019

While searching for a solution to a similar problem, I encountered this question, and can now add functionality to allow uploading large files (>25MB).
Essentially, the best thing to do would be to use a `multipart/form-data` request. **However** if you blithely do the following you'll encounter a problem:

```
let formData = new FormData()
let metadata = {
    PathOnClient: fileName, 
    ContentDocumentId: docId, 
    ReasonForChange : changeReason
    };
formData.append('entity_content', JSON.stringify(metadata));
formData.append('VersionData', fileField.files[0]);
...
xhr.send(formData);
```

You'll get a request built something like this:

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";

{
    "ContentDocumentId" : "069XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ReasonForChange" : "Marketing materials updated",
    "PathOnClient" : "Q1 Sales Brochure.pdf"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="Q1 Sales  Brochure.pdf"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

Now that is very similar to Salesforce's [example in the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion) except that it's missing a crucial line: `Content-Type: application/json` in the first part.
You'll get an error like so: `{message: "Multipart message must include a non-binary part", errorCode: "INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST"}` 
After much searching and anguish it turns out that this isn't Salesforce's fault! It's a general problem with the `FormData` object.

The solution is to generate your own request and send it. Like so:

```
<input type="file" #fileField name="fileName" />

let boundary = '----boundaryString';
...
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
xhr.send(new Blob([this.getRequestDataPart1(boundary), this.fileField.files[0], this.getRequestDataPart2(boundary)]));

getRequestDataPart1(boundary: string): string{
    let data =
    `--${boundary}
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
    Content-Type: application/json

    {
        "ContentDocumentId" : "069XXXXXXXXXXXX", //leave blank for new ContentDocument
        "ReasonForChange" : "Marketing materials updated", // not actually required
        "PathOnClient" : "${this.fileName}"
    }

    --${boundary}
    Content-Type: ${this.mimeType}
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="${this.fileName}"

    `;
    return data;
  }

  getRequestDataPart2(boundary: string): string{
    let data =
    `

    ----${boundary}--
    `;
    return data;
  }
```

I really hope that this helps someone. Maybe me in a year's time.

Comment: I tried using JSForce. It seems limit is just 10lakh characters approx 3-4mb. I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Thank you for documenting this solution, very valuable answer you have provided for constructing the multipart request manually to support > 25MB!

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by AvailableName works but I have spent multiple hours debugging because of how salesforce handles end of line symbols. I was getting an error saying that my data is in an incorrect format (maybe because of the editor I was using). To solve this I had to build the request like so:

```
sendXHR: function(component, helper, files, url, sessionId) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');      
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',  sessionId);
    var payloadPart1 = "--boundary_string" +
    "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"entity_content\";" +
    "\r\nContent-Type: application/json" +
    "\r\n\r\n{ \"FirstPublishLocationId\" : \"" + component.get('v.Id') + "\", \"PathOnClient\" : \"" + file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '.' + file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) + "\"}" +
    "\r\n\r\n--boundary_string" +
    "\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream" +
    "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"VersionData\"; filename=\"" + file.name + " \"" +
    "\r\n\r\n"; 
    var payloadPart2 = "\r\n\r\n--boundary_string--";
    xhr.send(new Blob([payloadPart1, file, payloadPart2]));
```

}